# How can i use same product detail page component everywhere in my reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a product Detail page on `/product-detail/:productId`. In my app I have different component which productlist.In one of the `ShopLiked Component` there is list of product and on clicking on product u go to product detail. but the problem is it does't redirect to same `product-detail/:productId` url instead it goes to `shop-liked/product-detail/:productId`. Is there any way to solve this so this can use the same `product-detail/:productId` component. or do I need to build seperate component for this.

This is how I am redirecting.

> ShopLikedProduct.jsx

```
<Grid key={data.productId} item xs={6}>
                            <Link to={`product-details/${data.productId}`}>
                        <MainCards data={data}/>
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
```

this goes to `/shop-liked/product-details/:productId` page instead i want it to go `product-detail/:productId` only.

Comment: Can you just specify the same `component` for the `Route` for `path="shop-liked/product-detail/:productId"`? It'll get the route props, so `props.match.params.producId` would exist.

Comment: You can do `<Link to={\`/product-details/${data.productId}\`}` (start the link with `/`)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 other things you can do:

1) use props.history:

```
function redirectHistory(url) {
    this.props.history.push(url);
}
```

2) Use Redirect component:

```
import Redirect from "react-router-dom";
function redirect(url) {
    return <Redirect to={url}/>;
}
```